# Redshift - Splitting data into multiple rows

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have sales data that shows customers that have bought a product. All customer IDs are appended to the same cell as shown below.

How could I split this such that I have one row per cust_id per prod_id

```
prod_id,cust_id
10001,100,101
10002,102
```

Expected output:

```
prod_id,cust_id
10001,100
10001,101
10002,102
```

Comment: Figured out the solution based on another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784721/redshift-split-single-dynamic-column-into-multiple-rows-in-new-table/46785509#46785509)

Comment: I am happy that it works for you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redshift split single dynamic column into multiple rows in new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784721/redshift-split-single-dynamic-column-into-multiple-rows-in-new-table)

Answer (score 0):

Since Redshift supports `generate_series` now, you can use the following SQL to achieve the desired result

```
with test(prod_id,cust_id) as (
select 10001,'100,101' union all
select 10002,'102'
),
max_ids as (
select distinct generate_series(1, regexp_count(cust_id,',') +1) n from test
)
select distinct prod_id, split_part(cust_id, ',', n) cust_id
from test, max_ids 
where split_part(cust_id, ',', n) != ''
```

output is

```
prod_id cust_id
10001   100
10001   101
10002   102
```

Comment: oh finally! what a breakthrough (RE supporting generate_series)