# How to write redshift aws query to search for a value in comma delimited values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

**table1**

| user_id | country_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'IN,AU,AC' |
| 2 | 'MX,IN' |

**table2**

| user_id | valid_country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'IN' |
| 1 | 'AU' |
| 2 | 'MX' |
| 3 | 'YT' |
| 4 | 'RU' |

As you can see, some entries in the country_code column are multiple codes separated by commas. I would like to print user_id in table1 and their corresponding country_code only if they are valid. To check for validity here I need to use table2 which has user_id and valid_country.

*The desired output is:*

| user_id | country_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'IN' |
| 1 | 'AU' |
| 2 | 'MX' |

Query looks like

> select tb1.user_id, country_code from table1 tb1, table2 tb2 where
> tb1.user_id=tb2.user_id and <Here I need to check if tb2.country_code
> is there in tb1.country_code (codes separated by commas)>

Are there any simple solution that I could check valid_country in the comma separated values.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46785509/5841306) answer your question..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way isn't always the best.  There are a number of corner cases that can arise here (like are all country codes 2 letters).  That said a LIKE clause would be simple:

```
select tb1.user_id, valid_country as country_code
from table1 tb1, table2 tb2 
where tb1.user_id=tb2.user_id 
  and tb1.country_code like '%'||tb2.valid_country||'%'
```

Or if we are to put this in modern SQL syntax:

```
select tb1.user_id, valid_country as country_code
from table1 tb1 join table2 tb2 
on tb1.user_id=tb2.user_id 
  and tb1.country_code like '%'||tb2.valid_country||'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

a) Verticalise `tb1` by `CROSS JOIN`ing it with a series of consecutive integers (which I supply in a Common Table Expression), and applying the `SPLIT_PART()` function to break the comma delimited list into single element.

b) `INNER JOIN` the verticalised result with the valid user_id/country code combinations table on an equi-join on both columns.

```
WITH   
-- your table 1, don't use in end query ...                                                                                                                                                                                      
tb1(user_id,country_code) AS (
          SELECT 1,'IN,AU,AC'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'MX,IN'
)
,
-- your table 2, don't use in end query ...                                                                                                                                                                                      
tb2(user_id,valid_country) AS (
          SELECT 1,'IN'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'AU'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'MX'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'YT'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'RU'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH" ...
,
i(i) AS ( -- need a series of integers ...
          SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4
UNION ALL SELECT 5
)
,
vertical AS (
  SELECT
    tb1.user_id
  , i
  , SPLIT_PART(country_code,',',i) AS valid_country
  FROM tb1 CROSS JOIN i
  WHERE SPLIT_PART(country_code,',',i) <> ''
)
SELECT
  vertical.user_id
, vertical.valid_country
FROM vertical
JOIN tb2 USING(user_id,valid_country)
ORDER BY vertical.user_id,vertical.i
;
-- out  user_id | valid_country 
-- out ---------+---------------
-- out        1 | IN
-- out        1 | AU
-- out        2 | MX
```