# How to map comma separated numbers to field names in another database table and concatenate the result?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a column of integer values that represent strings in another table. For example, say one column (let's call it `pets` in the users table) has values like `[1,3,4]` and another table called `pet_names` has rows like:

| Example | Id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | dog |
| 2 | 2 | cat |
| 3 | 3 | bird |
| 4 | 4 | lizard |

If the array value in the user table is `[1,2,4]`. I want a query that returns the string: "dog, birds, lizard" with spaces after the comma. How does one do this in postgres?

**EDIT**

Oh so sorry. since it's redshift it doesn't store the array data as an array. It's actually a string like "[1,2,4]".

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/73702485/6206 help you?

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need to unnest those array values into rows:

```
SELECT pet_id
FROM pets, unnest(pets_id_array_col) as pet_id
```

2. Select from `pet_names` using the result set from above:

```
SELECT Name
FROM pets
WHERE id in 
    (
        SELECT pet_id
        FROM pets, unnest(pets_id_array_col) as pet_id
    )
```

3. Finally you `STRING_AGG()` those names together:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(Name, ', ') as Names
FROM pets
WHERE id in 
    (
        SELECT pet_id
        FROM pets, unnest(pets_id_array_col) as pet_id
    )
```

This is a little ugly because storing data in an array/comma delimited list isn't a great choice, especially since you need to join on these values.

Comment: gonna try this. thank you so much

Comment: Oh so sorry. since it's redshift it doesn't store the data as an array. It's actually a string. What can I do to unnest the string representation of an array. The column type is varchar(512).

Comment: Oh. Yeah that's going to get ugly then. Without unnest or features in other RDBMS's like `unnest`, `strtok_split_to_table` or `STRING_SPLIT`, [redhat gets pretty ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784721/redshift-split-single-dynamic-column-into-multiple-rows-in-new-table/46785509#46785509). The real trick is splitting that comma delimited string into rows so you can join and string_agg.

Comment: so the query in the where clause is what needs to change right?

Comment: would something like this be useful? `SELECT     regexp_split_to_table(towns, E',') 
 FROM yourTable`