# Spreading the values of a row over multiple columns in a Redshift table?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table with an example row with the following structure:

```
id                url
12345             http://www.things.com/details/?foo=hello&bar=world&baz=John+Smith
45678             http://www.things.com/details/?foo=hello&bar=america&booz=Howard+Jones&other_field=Portugal
```

I would like to extract everything after the `?` in the url and for every `&`, add the value on the left of the `=` to a keys column and the value on the right to a values column.  There is no determinate number of `&`'s in a given URL.  The desired output is as follows:

```
id               key          value
12345            foo          hello
12345            bar          world
12345            baz          John+Smith
45678            foo          hello
45678            bar          america
45678            booz         Howard+Jones
45678            other_field  Portugal
```

My solution right now is to pick a reasonably high number and to write a Python script that writes the same query with a new `UNION ALL` for each integer.  I parse out the desired fields using `SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(url, '?', 2), '&', {i}), '=', 1)` and `SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(url, '?', 2), '&', {i}), '=', 2)` during each iteration.

Comment: Does Redshift have `regexp_split_to_table()`?

Comment: [No it does not.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a duplicate of a few other questions: [splitting rows in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779150/splitting-rows-in-redshift) , [Split values over multiple rows in RedShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921188/split-values-over-multiple-rows-in-redshift).

I don't think it's possible in Redshift easily, as AFAIK it doesn't have functions that convert a single row to multiple rows.

The related questions I mentioned also provide a few helpful tricks that might help. I think the best is one is joining with a table of sequence numbers (without any join predicates) and using that number for `SPLIT_PART`, possibly with a filter to eliminate rows that do not match.

Some other systems have functions for that, e.g. Postgres has `regexp_split_to_array` and `regexp_split_to_table`, and Snowflake has `SPLIT` + `FLATTEN` (disclaimer - I work on this system).